# Not able to display results in the console

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I made an application for storing data in CD. I want to just simply write the things into the console but I can't get printed on the console. Am I doing something wrong?

Here is my code whole demo application.

Here is my screen shot of `Core_Data_Demo_xcdatamodeld`

[image]

```
// AppDelegate.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;

- (void)saveContext;
- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory;    

@end

// AppDelegate.h

-(BOOL)createNewRectangleWithHeight:(NSInteger)heightParam width:(NSInteger)widthParam{

    if (heightParam ==0 || widthParam ==0) {
        NSLog(@"The height and width must no be 0");
        return NO;
    }

    Rectangle *rect = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Rectangle" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

    if (rect == nil) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to create new Rectangle");
        return NO;
    }

    rect.height = [NSNumber numberWithInt:heightParam];
    rect.width = [NSNumber numberWithInt:widthParam];

    NSError *savingError = nil;

    if ([self.managedObjectContext save:&savingError])  {
        return YES;
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Failed to save new person. Error = %@ ",savingError);
    }

    return  YES;
}


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    [self createNewRectangleWithHeight:2 width:2];

    return  YES;
}
```

Comment: What type of errors are you getting?

Comment: Which logs do don't see?

Comment: I don't get any NSLog statement.

Comment: for your information all the entities are created successfully. I check it with NSFetchRequest.

Comment: why do you expect to see any logs?.if an rectangle object is saved to the store, you will not see any logs..

Answer (score 1):

You are not able to see any statements because (I suppose) things run correctly.

If you want to retrieve data and print in the console you need to run a different method like `printData` or whatever you want. This method should set up a `NSFetchRequest` and execute it against your entity `Rectangle`.

```
- (void)printData {
    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Rectangle"];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *results = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    if(error) {
        // An error occurred
    } else {
        // See the results
    }
}
```

Usage

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // [self createNewRectangleWithHeight:2 width:2];
    [self printData];
    return  YES;
}
```

You should comment the `createNew...` method otherwise you will see multiple entries (equal to the number of times you've run the application) of `Rectangle` objects with the same `width` and `height`.

Answer (score 0):

The code which you have shown is for adding values using core data, If you do not get any error in the NSError object while you are adding the values then  data is successfully added inside the sqlite file.

To check the added values what you can do is use the SqliteManager addon from firefox and open the sqlite file (You can get the sqlite file location using `NSHomeDirectory()` method for it and then jump to the documents folder).

If you don't want the addon way you can always use `NSFetchRequest` to pull your data given below is the code for the same

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext*)getManagedObjectContext{
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
return appDelegate.managedObjectContext;
}

- (void)fetchdataFromDatabase{
    NSManagedObjectContext *appContext = [self getManagedObjectContext];
    if(appContext!=nil){
        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"YOUR_ENTITY_NAME" inManagedObjectContext:appContext];
        [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
        NSError *error = nil;
        NSArray *fetchedObjects = [appContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                                            error:&error];
        if(error!=nil && fetchedObjects.count!=0){
            // print your data here

        }else{
            //Print the error here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any reason for using `try-catch`? Are you able to indent the code? Thanks.

Comment: @flexaddicted : Many of the times i have messed up with predicates and have caught the exceptions with try-catch hence I use try-catch but for the above example it was not necessary to use them hence i have removed it. Thanks for pointing that out my bad.